# Standardized dependent variable, effect size interpretation

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, regression-coefficients, effect-size, standardization

I have the following model:

```
RT ~ condition + (1|participant)
```

RT is a continuous variable. Condition has three levels and is coded using Helmert contrasts.

I standardized the variable RT using scale(center == TRUE, scale == TRUE).

Can I know interpret the outcomes (differences between conditions) as "effect size" as it is usually done with standardized regression where dependent and independent variables are standardized? (At least in context of experimental setups using these three conditions.)

For me this would be logical, as it does not make sense to standardize the independent variable condition.

Comment: Z-score standardization basically converts the units of the variable to standard deviations. So you can interpret your coefficients in the typical way for Helmert contrasts, just with "standard deviations of RT" instead of "[whatever units] of RT".

Comment: @wzbillings Thanks, that's what I thought. So basically I can also say that I have BETA coefficients (standardized)?